# Random "SELECT 1" query in all requests on rails

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I'm profiling my rails 3.2 app with miniprofiler, and it shows me a

```
SELECT 1
```

query at the beginning of each page load or ajax call.  It only takes 0.4ms, but it is still a seemingly unnecessary database query.

Anyone know why this query is happening or how to get rid of it?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`SELECT 1` is like a ping - the cheapest query to test whether the session is alive and kicking. Various clients use it for that purpose. It may be useless in your case ...

Comment: So does it make sense to try to eliminate?  Is this inherent in all rails/activerecord apps?

Comment: @tyler You'll want to look into the Rails/ActiveRecord docs for that. It's probably set in the connection pooling options as an "aliveness check" or "connection validity check" of some form.

Answer (score 2):

For Postgres you can find it in this line on [Github](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.13/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb#L341).

Or, if you using MySQL, you can see the solution in [this groupon engineering blog](https://engineering.groupon.com/2013/rails/removing-the-ping-sting-from-rails-db-connections/).